# How can add javascript look up directories (searching paths) in intern.js

Tags: intern

How can add javascript look up directories (searching paths) in intern.js so that during define([..], function(..){..}) or require(..), intern.js will search requested relative script path in provided loop up directories.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behavior isn't controlled by Intern, but by the AMD module loader that implements `define` and `require`. AMD loaders don't search directories like the Node loader does; they have to know where to load a module from to start with.

When using relative paths, the loader will look relative to the file that is requesting a module. When using non-relative paths like `app/myModule`, the loader looks for `myModule` in the `app` package. It will look for `app` in the base directory (`project.cwd()` on Node). You can tell it to find app somewhere else using the `packages` entry in `loaderOptions` in your test config. Note that relative paths here are relative to the base directory, not to the test config file.

```
loaderOptions: {
    packages: [
        { name: 'app', location: '../some/other/dir' }
    ]
}
```

When one of your test modules uses a dependency like `app/myModule`, the loader will actually look for it in `<project dir>/../some/other/dir/myModule`.